# Different sections in a view in iOS

Tags: ios6

I want to achieve something like the next image at the bottom. Three sections which I can change touching in each option (Descripción, Video and Afiche). I don't know which UI components should I use according to iOS patterns and components. My workaround to achieve it would be use three buttons and when the user touch any of them I should hide the current view and show other view. Should I do my workaround or do you have any other suggestion? I'm developing from iOS 7. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your "workaround" sounds fine to me.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a UISegmentedControl to switch between views. I'm using a WebView and when user change between options I just change the WebView's content.

1. Assign selector to the UISegmentedControl

   [_segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
2. Method to change between views

   -(IBAction)segmentedControlClicked:(id)sender
    {
       if([sender selectedSegmentIndex]== 0 )
       {
           [_webViewContent loadHTMLString:desc baseURL:nil];
       }
       else if ([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
       {
           [_webViewContent loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
       }
       else if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 2)
       {
           [_webViewContent loadHTMLString:desc baseURL:nil];
       }
   }